# "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client." but i m using 'return' statements

Tags: node.js, express

I have a weird issue in NodeJS, Express and sequeilize. I was refactoring try/catch statements I facing this error. Specially, in postman when I send a signup post its work well but server is going to be shutting down.
[image]
[image]

I've already read enough of other solution, I used the return statement. but it still seems to be asynchronous somewhere. maybe... but I cant find that in the sentence..

I ever read that
('https://www.codementor.io/@oparaprosper79/understanding-node-error-err_http_headers_sent-117mpk82z8')

```
  signUpController: async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password, social } = req.body
    const userInfo = await user.findOne({
      where: {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        social: social
      },
    });
    try{
        if(userInfo === null){
          const newUser = await user.create({
            username,
            email,
            social : null,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
            profileimage: "default",
            total_time: 0,
          });
          return res.status(200).json(newUser);
        }
      }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).json({message : "invalid access"});
      }
      finally{
        return res.status(401).json({ message : "already exist"});
      }    
}
```

Comment: `finally` will execute code regardless of `resolve/try` or `reject/catch`, so your "already exists" message is trying to resend headers even though both your try (though conditionally) and catch already sent some. Try `finally { if( userInfo !== null ) return res.send... } ` and it should go away?

Comment: @somethinghere Ahh i understand. `catch` is already sent some but `finally` asynchronously sent again. right ? and i just try `finally { if( userInfo !== null ) return res.send... }` but it's still occurs.

Comment: Yes! Although because the strict inequality `!==` it might still execute if your block is `undefined` or something and not `null`. Maybe try `if( !userInfo )`. Either way, the error simply says headers have already been sent, so you are sending them twice, which means once in your `try/catch` and again in your `finally` block. @ĐăngKhoaĐinh has the answer that will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @somethinghere said, the `finally` block always executes, regardless of whether an error is thrown or not. You're trying the condition `if( userInfo !== null )` but the error still occurs, so I guess `userInfo` is a falsy value but doesn't strictly equal to `null`.

Because you're trying to refactor the code, I suggest the `exit early` pattern where you handle all invalid cases before the happy one. You can see my code below:

```
signUpController: async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password, social } = req.body
    const userInfo = await user.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email,
            username: username,
            social: social
        },
    });
    try {

        if (userInfo) {
            // early exit
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "already exist" });
        }

        // you don't need else here
        const newUser = await user.create({
            username,
            email,
            social: null,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
            profileimage: "default",
            total_time: 0,
        });
        return res.status(200).json(newUser);
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "invalid access" });
    }
    
    // you don't need the finally block 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. in this time, i came to understand a little more about try/catch. @Đăng Khoa Đinh  i can't tag well your id xd  but really thank you